# Currency field displaying as text in Apex

Tags: apex

For some reason when I do a debug statement and output the value of a currency field it loses it's formatting.  The field is on the Account object and it's a currency field and displays as such in the salesforce UI, but when I output it it shows as 8000 instead of $8,000 which is what I want.

```
for( Account a : accountList) {
  System.debug('Currency field ------------------' + a.Account_Limit__c);
}
```

It displays as just: 8000 with no formatting.

How can I maintain the currency formatting?

Answer (score 2):

Althought the field type is "Currency", that's just the *display* type, the rules used to diplay the value through the UI. The underlying type, how it's actually stored in Salesforce, is `Double`.

Knowing that is important, because the `Double` class has a `format()` method, which applies the formatting you're looking for.

So use `a.Account_Limit__c.format()` to get "8,000" (which would appear as "8.000" in many EU regions, the formatting applied is the appropriate one for your locale). Do note that `.format()` returns a string, so you won't be able to perform any math on that result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ConnectApi.UserSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_usersettings.htm) to get currency details.

```
String currencySymbol = ConnectApi.Organization.getSettings().userSettings.currencySymbol;
```

Then you can output your Decimal currency like this:

```
System.debug(currencySymbol + a.Account_Limit__c.format());
```

However, if you will set up currency that appears after amount, then you should replace symbol and actual amount.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to move the solution into the query.  SOQL gives you a format function that can be applied.  For example:

```
List<Opportunity> oprs = [select id, format(Amount) amt, Amount from opportunity limit 10];
for (Opportunity opr: oprs) {
    System.debug(opr.Amount);
    System.debug(opr.get('amt'));
}
```

This would output -to the developer console- both the Amount as 8000.00 and the currency as $8000.00 for the US locale.  If your user is in a different locale, for example Germany, then it might output 8000.00 and 8.000,00 €.  Note that Germany have a grouping symbol of a dot not a comma like in the US and it's decimal symbol is a comma not a dot.

If the code you're writing is for internal use then you can make assumptions but if it's packaged and deployed into customer orgs then currency and locale can be a world of pain especially if an org is a multi-currency org.